# Apache add header to request according to different domain

Tags: apache, http-headers

There are http://foo.com and https://secur.foo.com.

If request from https://secur.foo.com, I want to and some external information to request headers.

Could some body tell me how to complete above requirement?

---

I tried following steps to add header to request, but it failed.
1. Download a new httpd and install it.
2. Uncomment line “LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so”
3. Add following code at the end of "httpd.conf"

```
Header add myheader "myvalue"
RequestHeader set myheader2 "myvalue2"

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader append myheader3 "myvalue3"
</ifModule>
```

But I only find "myheader:myvalue" in response, how to make "myheader2" shows in request? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader append myheader2 "myvalue2"
</ifModule>
```

Comment: No, there is still no value for "myheader2".

Comment: Of course. You are looking for headers that was added to request by browser. Try to dumping request headers on server side, for example, if you are using PHP you can try next code: var_dump(getallheaders());

Comment: Cool... What a stupid mistake I made.
Can you tell me how to add header according to different domain? I don't want all my site have that header, I only want to add header to a specified sub-domain.

Comment: Why do you wont to use headers? You can set environment variable, by `SetEnvIf` directive, and then access it. For example `SetEnvIf Host ^.*secure.foo.com$ secure=1` in your htaccess will define env. "secure" only to secure.foo.com domain.

Comment: is there any way to check the newly added request header("myheader2") at the browser level without printing in the server? because My request URL is for woff2.                       https://XXXXXXXXX/font/Roboto/Medium/Roboto-Medium.woff2